How to delete unused subkeys from GPG key servers?
I'm trust trying to set up my GPG key again (after years of neglecting it). I have the private key and password and all, which is good.
After some trial and error I figured I used to create new pairs of subkeys in the past instead of adjusting the expire date and also did so during testing today.
So now I'm stuck with my public key and a bunch of subkeys attached to it.
I want my keypair to look like this, which is what I have set up locally in my GPG client:
pub   rsa4096 2019-06-18 [SC] [expires: 2027-10-22]
      D6C67D47E3F14DD581CA42F3548C284F527D7817
uid           [ultimate] Sebastian Mathes <s.mathes@posteo.de>
sub   rsa4096 2024-10-22 [E] [expires: 2027-10-22]

But whenever I upload my public key to the keyserver at https://keys.openpgp.org I get a public key with all the history attached to it.
This is the a view as seen from a public client:
seppo@sampo:~$ gpg --search-keys s.mathes@posteo.de
gpg: data source: https://keys.openpgp.org:443
(1) Sebastian Mathes <s.mathes@posteo.de>
      4096 bit RSA key 548C284F527D7817, created: 2019-06-18
Keys 1-1 of 1 for "s.mathes@posteo.de".  Enter number(s), N)ext, or Q)uit > 1
gpg: key 548C284F527D7817: public key "Sebastian Mathes <s.mathes@posteo.de>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
seppo@sampo:~$ gpg --list-options show-unusable-subkeys --list-keys
/home/seppo/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2019-06-18 [SC] [expires: 2027-10-22]
      D6C67D47E3F14DD581CA42F3548C284F527D7817
uid           [ unknown] Sebastian Mathes <s.mathes@posteo.de>
sub   rsa4096 2024-10-22 [E] [expires: 2027-10-22]
sub   rsa4096 2024-10-22 [E] [expires: 2027-10-22]
sub   rsa4096 2021-01-31 [S] [revoked: 2024-10-22]
sub   rsa4096 2019-06-18 [E] [revoked: 2024-10-22]
sub   rsa4096 2024-10-22 [E] [expires: 2027-10-22]
sub   rsa4096 2021-01-31 [E] [revoked: 2024-10-22]

Manually exporting and importing the keys works just fine but whenever I upload the key to the keyservers I get the same result.
Is there anything I am missing here?
